# Want to show data group by Year, Month, Week in openerp 7

Tags: odoo

I have a date field in my object, and from data field want to show data in group by. I have tried data group using likee this. But it has no effect.

example:

```
<filter icon="terp-go-year" string="Year"
                            domain="[('date_from','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('date_from','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01'))]"
                            help="Current Year"/>
                    <filter icon="terp-go-month" string="Month"
                            name="month"
                            domain="[('date_from','&lt;=',(datetime.date.today()+relativedelta(day=31)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('date_from','&gt;=',(datetime.date.today()-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
                            help="Current Month"/>
                    <filter icon="terp-go-week"
                            string="Week"
                            separator="1"
                            name="week"
                            domain="[('date_from','&lt;=', (datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(weeks=0,day=7, weekday=-1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('date_from','&gt;=',(datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(weeks=1, weekday=0)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
                            help="Current Week"/>
```

Its not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I have done some little changes.

```
<filter icon="terp-go-year" 
        string="Year"
        domain="[('date_from','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),'date_from','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01'))]"
        help="Current Year" 
        context="{'group_by':'date_from'}"/>

<filter icon="terp-go-month" 
        string="Month"
        name="month"
        domain="[('date_from','&lt;=',(context_today()+relativedelta(day=31)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('date_from','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
        help="Current Month" 
        context="{'group_by':'date_from'}"/>

<filter icon="terp-go-week"
        string="Week"
        separator="1"
        name="week"
        domain="[('date_from','&lt;=', (context_today() + relativedelta(weeks=0,day=7, weekday=-1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('date_from','&gt;=',(context_today() - relativedelta(weeks=1, weekday=0)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
        help="Current Week" 
        context="{'group_by':'date_from'}"/>
```

Here I have added `context="{'group_by':'date_from'}"` in every filter and instead `datetime.date.today()` I replaced it with `context_today()`.

Now it will work properly.

Comment: But for the current week filter, it doesnt return sunday/monday as the first day of the week, it returns records related to 7 days before the current date(todays date). If there is any records whose date_from is tomorrows date, then it will not be showed